# Displaying images and text in a column in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, html

I'm trying to create a 2 column layout with an image to the left and text to the right in wordpress. This needs to be a max of 600px width, the images will all be a fixed size of 250px wide and 142px high, and I will have image/text repeated below, as in this site http://housemusicpodcasts.co.uk/latest-podcasts/

All my attempts have led to the text just appearing below the images. I'd like to just be able to html/css without the need to change core files.

EDIT: Ok I have this code, but it does not align correctly, any ideas what I need to change?

```
<div class="pod">
<div class="singleblock">
<div class="wp-caption align:left;" style="width: 250px;"><img title="TEST" alt=""       src="http://www.djdavestewart.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/test.jpg" width="250" height="142" hspace="5" vspace="5" />
<p class="wp-caption-text">TEST CAPTION</p>

</div>
<p>TEXT HERE</p>
<p style="text-align:right;">Read More....</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="pod">
<div class="singleblock">
<div class="wp-caption align:left;" style="width: 250px;"><img title="TEST" alt="TEST" src="http://www.djdavestewart.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/test.jpg" width="250" height="142" hspace="5" vspace="5" />
<p class="wp-caption-text">TEST CAPTION</p>

</div>
<p style="text-align: left;">TEXT HERE</p>
<p style="text-align: right;">Read More....</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.pod p {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
float: left;
clear: right;
}

.singleblock {
float:left;
clear:left;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Gary

Comment: Read more about: [z-index](http://www.quackit.com/css/properties/css_z-index.cfm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for each couple of image/text, put them in a div. put a class on this div, and on use this CSS

```
.yourdive img{
  float : left;
}
```